# php get values from an array list?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

In php I am getting an array from the database. When I tried print_r($variable), I got the result like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [public_name] => Disk space
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [public_name] => Color
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [public_name] => Processor
        )

)
```

So here I want to get only the values Disk space, Color, Processor. So can someone kindly tell me how to get those values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
  echo $val["public_name"]."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use "array_column()" function if you are using PHP 5 >= 5.5.0.

```
$public_name = array_column($records, 'public_name');
print_r($public_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
foreach($variable as $row) {
    print $row['public_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Live demo : https://eval.in/92738
Use foreach :

```
foreach($your_array as $a){
  echo $a["public_name"]."<br />";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Disk space
Color
Processor
```

take a  look: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @Jagdish : did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

When this is a result from a Database why don't you use [`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

For example:

```
while ($resultarray = mysqli_fetch_array($variable))
{
echo $resultarray['public_name'];
}
```